# jquery ajax load and fade in joomla

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla2.5

in my joomla site i'm using this code to load the pages with Ajax:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery("#<?php echo $item->alias; ?>").click(function(){

    jQuery('#interno').fadeOut(500, function ck_load(){

    jQuery('#principale').load('<?php echo $ck_link; ?> #interno', function ck_fade_in() {

                jQuery('#interno').fadeIn(3000);

                });

          });

     });
});
```

in the index.php this is the structure of DIVs:

```
...
<div id="principale">
    <div id="interno">
        // Here is loaded the page from the component
    </div>
</div>
```

It works and load the page after the fade out of the container div (#interno); but the final callback function does not take effect (the fadeIn) and the page is loaded without any fade in effect... Can you help me to figure this out?

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` and then use `$` instead of `jQuery`.

Comment: still not working... The problem should be somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

you have passed a function variable as the callback function parameter for `.load`

You should pass a function like this:

```
jQuery('#principale').load('<?php echo $ck_link; ?> #interno', function() {

    jQuery('#interno').fadeIn(3000);

});
```

**Source(s)**

[jQuery API - .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: It was impossibile to make the fadein work properly, but i've solved the problem with animate opacity, in this way:

    jQuery('#principale').animate({opacity: 0.1}, 500).load('<?php echo $ck_link; ?> #interno').animate({opacity: 1}, 500);